# Equivalent of ByteSize() in protobuf

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Is there an equivalent of ByteSize() for protobuf in Java? I'm trying to get the size of a protobuf before serializing it.

Something like:

```
Protobuf.Builder buffer = Protobuf.newBuilder();
```

I need the size of the buffer now. Any idea how to obtain it?

Answer (score 6):

Build the protocol buffer, and call [`getSerializedSize()`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/MessageLite.html#getSerializedSize()).

Answer (score 3):

Answer:

```
Protobuf.Builder buffer = Protobuf.newBuilder(); 
int size = buffer.build().getSerializedSize();
```